# Select checkbox if not selected with Protractor

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox, protractor

I try execute in protractor following scenario:

1. Find checkbox
2. Check if it is selected

   - If yes - go further
   - If not - select it and go further

For some reason `isSelected()` function is not working with my checkbox, but I've found some solution. Below code works correctly:

```
expect(checkbox.getAttribute('aria-checked')).toEqual('false')
```

It checks some checkbox attribute which is 'false' if not selected and 'true' if selected. (but as a string)

Now the main question. How to write an 'if / else' statement to make it works?

I tried something like that:

```
if (expect(checkbox.getAttribute('aria-checked')).toEqual('false')) {
    checkbox.click();
}
```

But it always clicks on checkbox no mater if it was selected or not. I've tried also:

```
if (checkbox.getAttribute('aria-checked').toEqual('false')) {
    checkbox.click();
}
```

But there is an error which says "It's not a function".

Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method to solve the problem.

Before clicking any any checkbox, check for the value of `aria-checked` attribute, if its true don't do anything. Otherwise click on it.

```
checkBoxElement.getAttribute("aria-checked").then(function(isChecked){
   if(isChecked == "false") { //getAttribute will return the value as string.
       checkBox.click();
    }
})
```

Comment: It is not working for me, now it doesn't click in both cases. I think that because "aria-checked" is string value. (Not boolean?) But I might be wrong.

Comment: E.g.  checkbox.getAttribute("aria-checked").then(function(isChecked){
  expect(isChecked).toEqual(**'true'**);
})  **works ok**. But when I change toEqual(**true**); then I get an error that "Expected 'true' to equal true."

Comment: My Bad. `getAttribute` will return a string value. Instead of `if(!isChecked)`, use `if(isChecked == 'false')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make some helper function:

```
function setCheckBoxTo(locator, value){
    var checkbox = element(locator);
    checkbox.isChecked().then(function(selected){
        if(selected !== value){
            checkbox.click();
        }
    }
}
```

where  `[value is true/false]`